# Is this threadpool usage safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, locking, threadpool

I'm posting several jobs to a threadpool and then waiting for it to finish. I'm wondering if I've missed something here, since occasionally my worker threads seem to freeze.

My main thread start the workers like this:

```
numJobsPosted = 0;
for(auto entry : list)
{
    numJobsPosted++;
    threadPool->post(std::bind(&Controller::workerFunc, this, entry));
}

std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_workerLock);
while(numJobsPosted > 0)
{
    m_workerCondition.wait(lock);
}
```

Now my workerFunc looks something like this:

```
void Controller::workerFunc(Entry entry)
{
    // do some work with entry

    // notify finished
    numJobsPosted--;
    if(numJobsPosted <= 0)
    {
        // does the look need to be around the numJobsPosted-- ?
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(m_workerLock);
        m_workerCondition.notify_one();
    }
}
```

Is the above code safe, or do I need to put the lock around the decrement operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may depend on details of your thread pool's inner logic or setup (e.g. if you have a single thread, so jobs are actually run sequentially), but assuming that `numJobsPosted` is an `int` or similar built-in type, your code isn't thread-safe.
This line in `workerFunc`:

```
numJobsPosted--;
```

could very well be the subject of a race condition if it gets executed by several jobs concurrently.

Also, I'm not sure what your threadpool's `post` function does precisely, but if it dispatches the worker function to a thread right away and some of the worker functions can return immediately, you have another possible race condition between this line in your main thread code:

```
numJobsPosted++;
```

and this line in `workerFunc`:

```
numJobsPosted--;
```

To make it safe, you can for instance make `numJobsPosted` atomic, e.g. declare it like this (in C++11):

```
#include <atomic>
std::atomic_int numJobsPosted;
```

Making your `workerFunc` something like this:

```
void Controller::workerFunc(Entry entry)
{
    // do some work with entry

    // notify finished
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(m_workerLock);
        numJobsPosted--;
        if(numJobsPosted <= 0)
        {
            m_workerCondition.notify_one();
        }
    }
}
```

may solve the first race condition case, but not the second.

(Also, I don't really understand the logic around the manipulation and testing you're doing on `numJobsPosted`, but I think that's beside the point of your question)

Comment: Yeah so numJobsPosted was a regular int, I'll change it to be atomic. About the code you posted, I'll ofcourse need to decrease the numJobsPosted, even if it's greater than 1, I guess I'll just move the lock around the operator-- for now. Thanks.